# View Linked Server history and see if and how it has been accessed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have three linked servers linked to our sales system database.

We need to view, what if any are in use and by whom?

Is there a view to view these details in SQL Server?

Thanks

Comment: SELECT t.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
WHERE UPPER(t.[text]) LIKE N'%OPENQUERY%';

Comment: Thanks Ali, is there any way to see who or what ran the script against the Linked Server?

Comment: Please note that using the above will work but it is NOT 100% accurate. There are other ways to use linked server than openquery. You can simply do a select statement with four part naming. Also, once a plan is no longer cached it will not be returned.

Comment: (And not all usage will be in the plan cache, either due to age or never getting in there in the first place.)